# Adaptive Layout UICollectionViewCell Size for Different iDevices

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, adaptive-layout

I am using adaptive layout for different iDevices screen sizes, I am having troubles showing two cells in portrait orientation. I designed a cell say 130 x 210 which looks perfect on iPhone 5, but when in iPhone 6 we have more 30 px, for which i calculate remaining space and set space equally, but that looks ugly see

[image]

As I go on iPhone 6+ it looks more weird, and on iPad there will be more number of cells in a row, recommend me a way to deal with this situation or should I calculate size of the item every time and number of items the screen can contain so space accordingly. This is how I am calculation for now

```
int space = self.view.frame.size.width;
space = space - 130 *2;
space = space/3;
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = space;
flow.minimumLineSpacing = space;
flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(space, space, space, space);
flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(130, 210);
[self.collectionViewGames setCollectionViewLayout:flow];
```

Comment: I think its better to have almost constant space between cells in all the devices and the item size can be changed based on the device.

Comment: @sateesh yes its an option to change the width of the cell according, lets say fix space to 20 px, and set the width. But as its adaptive layout, on iPad it will go really bad with that much width, can put a special check for iPad though, but some proper solution !

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem while implementing an app similar to Photos app. what i have done here is I fixed the size of spacing to a constant value. and based on the remaining space i calculated the item size.

Here is the code in my case

```
 var flowLayout = // your flow layout


        var itemWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / (5) // i am using 5 cells in a row
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(itemWidth - 2, itemWidth - 2)
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0 , bottom: 0, right: 0)
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
```

Comment: this is exactly my other solution, I will add a check for iPad then, if i find no other possible solution